# extract certain emails from a given list of email matching few conditions

Tags: php, email

This question was asked in a recent job interview I gave and I was unable to answer it. Here is the question:

From a given email list (johndoe@noemail.com, xyz@no-email.com, noemail@xyz.com, answers@no email.com, jpt@nooooemail.com, kondoe@nomail.com) extract only those emails ending with (@noemail.com, @no-email.com, and @no email.com).

I searched and tried to run the code but it didn't ran.

```
<?php

  $email_list = (johndoe@noemail.com, xyz@no-email.com, noemail@xyz.com, answers@no email.com, jpt@nooooemail.com, kondoe@nomail.com);

  $pattern = ('@noemail.com', '@no-email.com', '@no email.com' );

  echo preg_match($pattern, $email_list);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$email_list = array('johndoe@noemail.com', 'xyz@no-email.com',
                    'noemail@xyz.com', 'answers@no email.com',
                    'jpt@nooooemail.com', 'kondoe@nomail.com');
$result = array();

foreach ($email_list as $email) {
    if (preg_match('~@no[ -]?email\.com~', $email)) {
        $result[] = $email;
    }
}

var_export($result);
// output ->
//        array (
//          0 => 'johndoe@noemail.com',
//          1 => 'xyz@no-email.com',
//          2 => 'answers@no email.com',
//        )
```

Comment: This is a better solution than mine, as it uses preg_match what you wanted to use. Mine is a more simple approach, where I traverse both arrays and try to match them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$email_list = array("johndoe@noemail.com", "xyz@no-email.com", "noemail@xyz.com", "answers@no email.com", "jpt@nooooemail.com", "kondoe@nomail.com");
$matchlist = array("@noemail.com", "@no-email.com", "@no email.com");

function str_contains($haystack, $needle) {
    return (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false);
}

foreach ($email_list as $email) {
    foreach($matchlist as $match) {
        if (str_contains($email, $match)) {
            echo $email . "<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Not the perfect way, but works.